# Texture mapping sphere in ray tracing

Tags: c++, graphics, texture-mapping, raytracing

I'm trying to texture a sphere using a .bmp image with cimg but its not texturing properly.
heres the texture image
[texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sinf1.png)

This is the result. [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QPef.png)

Here's my code for calculating the color at the intersection point.

```
virtual RGBColor getTexture(Point3D pos){
    //normal of intersection point and sphere
    Vector3D N = this->getNormal(pos);
    N.normalize();


    double u = 0.5 + atan2(N.getY(), N.getX()) / (2 * 3.141592653589793);
    double v = 0.5 - asin(N.getY()) / 3.141592653589793;

    CImg<int> image("pattern.bmp");
    float width = u * 150;//105 is image width
    float height = v * 105;
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;

     r = image(width, height, 0, 0);
     g = image(width, height, 0, 1);
     b = image(width, height, 0, 2);

    return(RGBColor(r,g,b));
}
```

Pos is the point of intersection.
Any help is apreciated

Comment: If "105 is image width," then why are you multiplying by 150?  Why don't you use `image.width()` and `image.height()` to make sure you get those values right?  Why not add some assertions to make sure `u` and `v` are normalized correctly?

Comment: Thanks for replying. 105 was a typo and I'm not very familiar with Cimg so I didnt know about .width(). I added assert statements for u,v, width and height but I'm still getting the same result

Comment: Why is the sphere oblong (wider than tall)?  It suggests you have other geometry problems going on.

Comment: I think that's caused by my FOV and screen width not being setup properly but I'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: I feel like a fool. my vector getXYZ methods were all returning z. thanks a lot for your help